# Решение квадратного уравнения

Tags: java

```
public class Equation {

    public static double a;
    public static double b;
    public static double c;

    public int kol;

    public int kolkorni() {
        if (a != 0) {
            if (b * b - 4 * a * c > 0) {
                kol = 2;
            }
        }
        if ((a == 0) && (b != 0) && (c != 0)) {
            kol = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: да практически ничего не реализовали

Comment: Вижу только "метод вычисления количества корней" при чем, судя по условию задачи, он не должен быть статическим.

Comment: а что должно получиться в результате этого метода? метод отображения хранящейся в объекте информации

Comment: Наверное немного не так понял... Поправлю ответ...

Comment: Вроде все реализовала?

Comment: Нет. Конструктора нет.
Конструктор это: 
    public Equation(double a, double b, double c){
       this.a = a;
       this.b = b;
       this.c = c;
    }

А метод set, если уж делаешь, то лучше делать для каждого поля отдельно. setA, setB, setC

Comment: У вас корни k1, k2 и их количество kol реализованы в виде свойств класса. Это не вполне логично. Коэффициенты уравнения могут изменяться, вы же сделали им сеттеры. Либо после присвоения вызывайте метод korni, либо реализуйте вместо свойств методы их расчета

Comment: Метод отображения хранящейся в объекте информации - это toString(). А все printABC не нужны, уберите их

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опишу то, как я понял эту задачу:

1. Определить переменные класса. В классе нужно определить поля (в вашем случае типа double) a, b, c.
2. Конструкторы. Конструктор, навскидку, нужен 1. Он должен устанавливать значения a, b и c.
3. Метод вычисления количества корней. Исходя из первых 2х пунктов было бы логично сделать метод нестатичным и чтобы он возвращал количество, или записывал бы его в отдельное поле класса (за правильность алгоритма работы самого метода не ручаюсь, ибо вопрос был не об этом).
4. Метод отображения хранящейся в объекте информации. Для всех полей написать методы print, суть которых сводилась бы просто к выводу на экран значения переменной.
   Например,

   ```
   void printA(){
     System.out.println(a);
   }
   ```

Comment: я не понимаю за чем нужны методы для вывода всех членов уравнения. Если уж пишите на джаве - переопределяйте метод toString().

Answer (score 3):

Первое - поубирать все `static` - они точно здесь не нужны.

```
public static double a;
public static double b;
public static double c;
```

их ещё сделать и приватными.

Для корней не принято давать имена k1 и k2, а x1 и x2. Вам то может и понятно, а стороннему человеку (преподавателю к примеру), нужно это будет ещё догадаться.

Метод korni наверное лучше назвать solve, findRoots или что то в этом стиле.  Беглый анализ этого метода показывает, что ситуация, когда дескриминант равен нулю  не обрабатывается.

Методы printA, printB, printC - излишни (если только не была поставлена задача их написать). Я бы лучше добавил метод "printSolution", который бы распечатал само уравнение, дискриминант и корни в красивой форме.

Comment: Метод отображения хранящейся в объекте информации - и есть причина появления printA,B,C.
Сами корни, если вы не заметили, НЕ вычисляются. Вычисляется их количество.

Comment: а что это такое `k1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a);` если  не первый корень???

Comment: Ок. Согласен. Просто в код метода не посмотрел. В задании то вычисления корней нет.

Answer (score 3):

Если спрашивают кол-во корней, то считать их не будем. Если хотите возвращать в целых, то в третьем случаи вернем максимальный для инта вариант. Один момент еще - double так сравнивать нельзя.

```
public class Equation {

    private double a;
    private double b;
    private double c;

    public Equation(double a, double b, double c){
        this.set(double a, double b, double c);
    }

    public void set(double a, double b, double c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public double getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public double getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public double getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public int resultsNuber() {
        if (isQuadratic()) {
            double discriminant = this.getDiscriminant();
            if (discriminant > 0) {
                return 2;
            } else if (discriminant == 0.0) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        if (isLinear()) {
            return 1;
        }

        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    private boolean isQuadratic() {
        return a != 0;
    }

    private boolean isLinear() {
        return (a == 0) && (b != 0) && (c != 0);
    }

    private double getDiscriminant() {
        return b*b - 4*a*c;
    }

    public void toString() {
        return "" + a + "*x^2 + " + b +"*x + " + c + " = 0";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Я бы для получение гарантированной 5+ в дополнении к ответу @Антон_Феоктистов создал бы иерархию классов (геттеры/сеттеры намеренно опущены):

```
public abstract class Equation {
    protected double static epsilon=0.0000001; //значение зависит от задачи
    protected double a;
    protected Equation(double a) {this.a=a;}
    protected boolean isZero(double x) {
        if(Math.abs(x) <= epsilon)
           return true;
        return false;
    }
    public abstract int getNumberOfRoots();
}

public class LinearEquation extends Equation {
    protected double b;
    public LinearEquation(double a, double b) {super(a); this.b=b;}
    public int getNumberOfRoots() {
       if(this.isZero(b)
          return 0;
       return 1;
    }

public class QuadraticEquation extends LinearEquation {
    protected double c;
    public LinearEquation(double a, double b, double c) {super(a, b); this.c=c;}
    public int getNumberOfRoots() {
       //blah-blah
    }
}
```

Comment: Согласен! Так выглядет завершенней. Да, как раз Math.abs(x) <= epsilon об этом я только упомянул, но писать стало лень)